# Shortening javascript code with extend or etc

Tags: javascript, extend

I have a function like that:

```
initGrid: function(tableGridId, url) {
        var deviceTableGridId;
        if (typeof tableGridId != "undefined"){
            deviceTableGridId = tableGridId;
        } else {
            deviceTableGridId = gridId;
        }
        var getUrl;
        if (typeof url != "undefined"){
            getUrl = url;
        } else {
            getUrl = restUrl;
        } 
..
}
```

How can I write that code shorter? I mean with extend or etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var deviceTableGridId = tableGridId || gridId,
        getUrl = url || restUrl;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
initGrid: function(tableGridId, url) {
    tableGrid = tableGrid || gridId;
    url || (url = restUrl);
    ...
}
```

The patterns for default parameter values are as such

`x = x || someValue;`

and

`x || (x = someValue);`

Note both checks, check for truthy values, so they will override `false`, `""`, `0`, etc.

If you want something more secure try

`x === undefined && (x = someValue);`

Answer (score 0):

Both the other solutions are great when `falsy` values can be excluded from the acceptable input. If it can't be however, then a simple helper function will clean things up;

```
function getOrDefault(val, other) {
    if (typeof val == "undefined") {
        return other; 
    }

    return val;
}

var someVal = getOrDefault(someVar, 4);
var getUrl = getOrDefault(url, restUrl);
```

Another approach would be;

```
var someVal = someVar;

if (typeof someVal == "undefined") {
    someVal = 4;
}

var getUrl = url;

if (typeof getUrl == "undefined") {
    someVal = restUrl;
}
```

Although hopefully you'll favour the first solution.